# Nunjucks nested blocks

Tags: nunjucks

I'm just getting started with Nunjucks and am having trouble getting nested blocks to work. I have a controller block with some code, inside of which the content should be nested. But when I specify the content in my template file, it doesn't appear in the HTML output from Nunjucks. Here are the files (simplified):

components/controller.html.njk:

```
<div id="controller">
    {% block controllerContent %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

layouts/layout.html.njk:

```
{% include "components/controller.html.njk" %}
```

index.html.njk:

```
{% extends "layouts/layout.html.njk" %}

{% block controllerContent %}
  CONTROLLER CONTENT HERE
{% endblock %}
```

How can I get the content specified in controllerContent to show up inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `hml.njk` extension? Either one of those should work. I tend to use .njk for dev phase and gulp outputs them as html in dist.

To solve your problem - you actually have different solutions here:

1. Have controller content available globally (every page that extends layout.njk will have it)

**layouts/layout.njk:**

```
<div id="controller">
  {% include "components/controller.njk" %}
</div>
```

**index.njk** (or any other page for that matter)

```
{% extends layouts/layout.njk %}
```

**components/controller.njk:** (doesn't even have to be defined as block if you only use it as included - it can be pure html)

```
<ACTUAL CONTROLLER CONTENT HERE>
```

2. Other case is if you want only home page (index.html) to have this code, while other pages don't

**layouts/layout.njk:**

```
{% block base %}
{% endblock %}
```

**index.njk**

```
{% extends layouts/layout.njk %}

{% block base %}
  <div id="controller">
    {% include "components/controller.njk" %}
  </div>
{% endblock % }
```

**components/controller.njk:**

```
<ACTUAL CONTROLLER CONTENT HERE>
```

There's actually much more possible variations (it all depends on specifics of your project) but you need to understand how inheritance works. Once you get used to it, it will be much easier. I've also had adjusting phase in the beginning.

Hope this helps.